# How can I use loadUrl or loadFile in production with Electron and CRA?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, electron, fetch, electron-builder

I have build an application with Electron and Create React App. I used `"proxy": "http://192.168.1.10:3000"` inside package.json in development. Then I generated exe file with electron builder according to this article: [medium](https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3)

My main electron file is:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const path = require("path");
const url = require('url');

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: 'preload.js',
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 600,
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);

}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

My app is building fine but when I send a request to my node server I am getting:
`POST file:///D:/api/auth/login net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I am quite confused now. How can I set a default proxy for my app for requesting to the server as well as loading the file form the build folder?

[image: Image from project]

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions

Comment: Here it is written I need to serve it from server by pushing the index.html from build folder. But my Node JS server and CRA are in different folders. BTW, I want to deploy the server on the internet. Not sure what to do ((